# How to get Holder data and pass it through intent correctly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've read an article on [Medium](https://medium.com/master-of-code-global/recyclerview-tips-and-recipes-476410fa12fd) about `Recyclerview` and it states there that, it is a bad practice to put a listener inside `onBindViewHolder`.

In my case, I declare some listener inside it, just to go to the next `Activity`

```
holder.readMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //INTENT BUNDLE HERE

            }
        });
```

**Is there an alternative way of of getting the set data from the holder and pass it through intent?**

```
holder.textViewTitle.setText(doctrines.get(position).doctrineTitle);
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(doctrines.get(position).doctrineSummary);
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

EDIT: Provide modified full code

public class AdapterDoctrines extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context mContext;
public List<ModelGreatDoctrines> doctrines;

public Intent bundleData;

public AdapterDoctrines(Context mContext, List<ModelGreatDoctrines> doctrines) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.doctrines = doctrines;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DoctrinesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View viewDoctrineCard;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflaterCard;

    layoutInflaterCard = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    viewDoctrineCard = layoutInflaterCard.inflate(R.layout.card_doctrine,parent,false);

    return new DoctrinesHolder(viewDoctrineCard);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DoctrinesHolder holder, int position) {

    //ModelGreatDoctrines greatDoctrines = doctrines.get(position);




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return doctrines.size();
}

class DoctrinesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    CardView mCardView;

    AppCompatTextView textViewTitle;

    AppCompatTextView textViewDesc;

    AppCompatButton buttonRead;

    AppCompatButton buttonDownload;

    public DoctrinesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_great_doctrine);
        mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);

        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_title);
        textViewDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_desc);

        buttonRead = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_read);
        buttonRead.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_download);
        buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.card_great_doctrine:

                break;

            case R.id.card_doctrine_read:
                //INTENT BUNDLE EXTRA - NEXT ACTIVITY

                break;


            case R.id.card_doctrine_download:
                //PERFORM DOWNLOAD USING DOWNLOAD MANAGER

                break;

        }

    }

    //BUNDLE INTENT
    public void intentBundle(){
        bundleData = new Intent(mContext,ViewerDoctrineActivity.class);

        // GET data from Holder

        bundleData.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        mContext.startActivity(bundleData);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes it is a bad practice to implement the `OnClickListener` inside the `onBindView` method. Instead you should implement it inside the `ViewHolder` class. If you add your `RecyclerView` class, I would be able to help out

Comment: @Napster - I pasted the code, my problem is, is how to access the data from the holder. Should I create a method for it?

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach to get the data from your bundle from `ViewHolder` class.

First, create your own onClickListener class (you can do this inside your `ViewHolder` class):

```
  public class RecyclerViewItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ModelGreatDoctrines doctrine;

    RecyclerViewItemClickListener(ModelGreatDoctrines doctrine){
      this.doctrine = doctrine;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      int id = view.getId();
      switch (id){
        case R.id.card_great_doctrine:

          break;

        case R.id.card_doctrine_read:
          intentBundle(doctrine);
          break;


        case R.id.card_doctrine_download:
          //PERFORM DOWNLOAD USING DOWNLOAD MANAGER

          break;

      }
    }
  }
```

Second, update your code for the `ViewHolder` class:

```
class DoctrinesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

CardView mCardView;

AppCompatTextView textViewTitle;

AppCompatTextView textViewDesc;

AppCompatButton buttonRead;

AppCompatButton buttonDownload;

public DoctrinesHolder(View itemView) {
super(itemView);
    ModelGreatDoctrines greatDoctrines = doctrines.get(getAdapterPosition());
    RecyclerViewItemClickListener itemClickListener = new RecyclerViewItemClickListener(greatDoctrines)
    mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_great_doctrine);
    mCardView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);

    textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_title);
    textViewDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_desc);

    buttonRead = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_read);
    buttonRead.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);

    buttonDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_doctrine_download);
    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);

     }
}
```

Third, change the method `intentBundle` to accept `ModelGreatDoctrines` as a parameter:

```
//BUNDLE INTENT
public void intentBundle(ModelGreatDoctrines doctrine){
    bundleData = new Intent(mContext,ViewerDoctrineActivity.class);

    // GET data from Holder

    bundleData.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mContext.startActivity(bundleData);
}
```

And now you have your current doctrine inside your `intentBundle` method so you can use it to get the data

Answer (score 0):

At first create an interface-

```
public interface ItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(int pos);
}
```

Now, Inside your adapter class declare an inner public class MyViewHolder which implements the interface-

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(this.getLayoutPosition());
    }
}
```

Then, inside your onBindViewHolder, you can implement the setItemClickListener method like below and pass the data -

```
holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int pos) {

              Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("data_name", "your data");
              context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are adding an `OnClick` callback in `onBindView`, which is what he is trying to move away from because `onBindView` gets called  multiple times for every element on scroll and is bad for performance